# Not able to bind second array to angular-dual-listbox

Tags: angular, listbox, angular-cli, angular9

I am trying to bind my JSON to Confirmed list of angular-dual-listbox which is provided by czeckd
But source part is showing correct and Destination list is not showing.

I have created one stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/dual-list-example?file=src/app/app.component.html

Please help me
Reference:
https://github.com/czeckd/angular-dual-listbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dual list source needs to contain all devices:

```
this.source = [...this.sourceDevice, ...this.confirmedDevice];
```

[Fixed stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dual-list-example-skei2w?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for help. Please let me know why we use three dots before? I am new to it. Please mark up to my question

Comment: those 3 dots are called spread operator its new feature of js as from ES6 standard. For array variable it explodes array elements and so they can be used to create new array or be passed as function arguments (so in this example above it takes all elements from this.sourceDevice and this.confirmedDevice and creates one big array). For Objects it would also include object keys in general i sugges lookup es6 spread operator and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax